# querystring parameters in callback URL for AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I was using the default login page for cognito & trying to pass query parameters in the callback URL. It seems to work only with 1 query param but not 2 (did not try more than that). I tried encoding the query parameters of the URL (as was mentioned in some posts here) but did not work.
What works

- http://localhost:6768/portal.html?up=us-east-2_4AIAW7KJa

what doesn't work

- http://localhost:6768/portal.html?up=us-east-2_4AIAW7KJa&idp=us-east-2:2a45e21c-2541-4dcc-9edb-3015ee5fcb96
- http://localhost:6768/portal.html%3Fup%3Dus-east-2_4AIAW7KJa%26idp%3Dus-east-2%3A2a45e21c-2541-4dcc-9edb-3015ee5fcb96

Any clue how to make this work? For now, I have cheated & feeding it as val1=val2 & parsing it out.

I created the user pool, identity pool using cloud formation scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Response from AWS -

> In the console you should provide the unencoded URL -
>   https://www.google.com?val1=a&val2=b. When accessing the hosted UI you
>   have to provide the encoded redirect URL -
>   redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fval1%3Da%26val2%3Db
>
> Hope this helps!

Comment: But surely this means you have to define the values of val1 and val2 in the console? I get a URL_MISMATCH if I try to pass to the hosted UI, for example, redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fval1%3Dfoo%26val2%3Dbar

Answer (score 10):

This is the purpose of the `STATE` variable - [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) & [Reference](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/58).

To properly configure the state variable: `&state=testparam1=param+testparam2=newparam`

Comment: That works, so thanks. Though I am not convinced that's the purpose of the `STATE` variable.

Comment: I agree the documentation is a little vauge.. this forum also has discussion over using the state as such: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/78, but it seems other developers are using it in a broad range. These updates are also fairly recent <6 mo