# AWS cognito - Add acr_values parameter to authorize URL supplied by Cognito when calling OIDC provider

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I have an OpenID Connect Identity provider set up in an AWS Cognito user pool. When trying this URL in a browser:

`https://<my_user_pool_domain>/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=<callback_uri>&response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&identity_provider=<my_oidc_provider>`

Cognito redirects to my OIDC provider with the following URL

`https://<my_oidc_provider>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<oidc_client_id>
&redirect_uri=https://<my_user_pool_domain>/oauth/idpresponse&scope=openid&response_type=code&state=<state>`

But this is where I’m stuck because the provider requires acr_values as a param. Is it possible to have Cognito add `&acr_values=<my_values>` to the query?

Comment: If the below answer is correct, could you please accept it ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I'm also facing similar kind of problem, how to maintain query string in cognito callback. I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143646/querystring-parameters-in-callback-url-for-aws-cognito/51308969 but not working

Answer (score -4):

Append your extra params *acr_values=< my_values>* in the redirect URI itself.

```
redirect_uri=https://<my_user_pool_domain>/oauth/idpresponse?acr_values=<my_values>
```

Register the same URI in the Cognito user pool as well.

Comment: It’s a parameter to the /authorize request I want to append, not the redirect_uri